# What to do with Question in which error was because of a mistake I solved myself, but was not related

Tags: support, close-reasons

I asked a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213480/submit-button-in-form-doesnt-work-though-page-reloads), in which 2 users answered but none of them worked for me. However, I myself realized some time later that the bug was caused by a piece of code which was existing at the top of my program, but was not related to to the error itself.

The question is now quite old, and cannot be deleted. How should I close it now (what reason)?

Comment: Good job on you for wanting to clean up a bad question. :)

Comment: @Draco18s I just don't want them appearing! 

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the resolution is really irrelevant to what you posted in the question, it fits the "resolved in a manner unlikely to help other users" close reason. So, vote to close as such **and add a comment for reviewers**, or just delete it if you can.

That said, if the code you posted was not the one causing the error, it's not an [MCVE](/help/mcve), and thus the question was close-worthy in the first place.

Comment: That's right. The error wasn't in the code I posted. And the post cannot be deleted as it has got 2 answers too.

Comment: What reason should I give to close the question?

Comment: @MrigankPawagi I wrote which: "as such" -- which means: "with the aforementioned reason".

Answer (score 8):

There is a specific close off-topic reason for this:

"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."